# Calling a function and unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, function

I am trying to call a function that I wrote like this

```
func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    var showResult: NADInterstitialShowResult
    showResult = NADInterstitial.sharedInstance().showAd()

    switch(showResult.rawValue){
    case AD_SHOW_SUCCESS.rawValue:
        print("広告の表示に成功しました。")
        break
    case AD_SHOW_ALREADY.rawValue:
        print("既に広告が表示されています。")
        break
    case AD_FREQUENCY_NOT_REACHABLE.rawValue:
        print("広告のフリークエンシーカウントに達していません。")
        break
    case AD_LOAD_INCOMPLETE.rawValue:
        print("抽選リクエストが実行されていない、もしくは実行中です。")
        break
    case AD_REQUEST_INCOMPLETE.rawValue:
        print("抽選リクエストに失敗しています。")
        break
    case AD_DOWNLOAD_INCOMPLETE.rawValue:
        print("広告のダウンロードが完了していません。")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

and I am calling in the viewdidload like this

```
showButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

I get an error saying fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. What am I doing wrong? any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you able to add an exception breakpoint to see where the problem is exactly?

Comment: It looks like you are using the cordova plugin. My guess is that NADInterstitial.sharedInstance() is returning nil, and then you are trying to call showAd(), which results in the crash you are seeing. However, looking at the git repository only the headers are available, so I can't be 100% certain. Put a break point on the line: showResult = NADInterstitial.sharedInstance().showAd() and then use your step in and out controls to make certain the value is not nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `showButton` nil? If it is an `@IBOutlet`, it may not be wired up in your storyboard or xib.